# Hacer un UPDATE reemplazando una parte específica en una posición específica de la columna en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, update

Tengo una columna con valores así:

```
ol_biblica
--------------
0107010101
0107010201
0107010301
0107010401
0107010501
0107010601
0107010701
```

Y me gustaría hacer un reemplazo del caracter que está **en la 4ª posición** contando de izquierda a derecha, cambiando ese `7` por un `8`. Nótese que en la última fila hay un `7` también en la 8ª posición y que **ese no tiene que cambiar**, solamente el valor de la 4ª posición.

La actualización quedaría así:

```
ol_biblica
--------------
0108010101
0108010201
0108010301
0108010401
0108010501
0108010601
0108010701
```

Yo sé seleccionar con un `LIKE`, pero no sé como hacer un `UPDATE` basado en algo parecido.

Por ejemplo si ejecuto esta consulta me trae todas las `ol_biblica` que tienen esa secuencia, indistintamente del valor penúltimo (que representaría el día de la semana):

```
SELECT 
    dia,
    semana,
    ol_biblica 
FROM liturgia 
WHERE 
    id_tiempo=1 
    AND semana=1 
    AND ol_biblica 
    LIKE '0107010_01' 
ORDER BY dia;
```

La cuestión sería hacer un `UPDATE` parecido a ese `SELECT`, que me filtre así: `0107010_01` y me reemplace el `7` (4ª posición) por un `8`. La columna tiene siempre 10 caracteres.

¿Cómo podría hacer ese `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar [`INSERT(str,pos,len,newstr)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_insert):

> Devuelve la cadena `str`, con la subcadena que comienza en la posición `pos` y los caracteres `len` reemplazados por la cadena `newstr`. Devuelve la cadena original si `pos` no está dentro de la longitud de la cadena. Reemplaza el resto de la cadena desde la posición `pos` si `len` no está dentro de la longitud del resto de la cadena. Devuelve `NULL` si algún argumento es `NULL`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
UPDATE liturgia 
SET ol_biblica = INSERT(ol_biblica, 4, 1, '8')
WHERE id_tiempo = 1 
    AND semana = 1 
    AND ol_biblica LIKE '0107010_01'
```

Comment: Excelente solución!

Comment: Me quedo con esta solución porque me parece la más clara y la más controlable, le agregué un `LIMIT 7` para evitar sorpresas. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Con este `select` detectas aquellos registros que tienen un siete el la posición 4 del campo `ol_biblica`

```
SELECT dia, semana, ol_biblica
FROM liturgia 
WHERE 
id_tiempo=1 
AND semana=1 
AND SUBSTRING(ol_biblica, 4, 1) = '7'
ORDER BY dia;
```

Con este `update` rehaces el valor del campo `ol_biblica` poniendo en la cuarta posición un 8 cuando hay un 7.

```
UPDATE liturgia
SET ol_biblica = SUBSTRING(ol_biblica, 1, 3) + '8' + SUBSTRING(ol_biblica, 5, 6)
WHERE SUBSTRING(ol_biblica, 4, 1) = '7'
```

Answer (score 1):

Si el campo es un número, puedes aprovechar y simplemente sumar la cantidad equivalente.

```
UPDATE liturgia SET ol_biblica=ol_biblica+1000000
WHERE SUBSTRING(ol_biblica, 4, 1) = '7'
```

Si no es un número siempre, la mejor solución es con SUBSTRING()

Comment: Es buena la idea, solo que así como esta cambia el formato, por ejemplo, a `0107010101` quedaria como `108010101`. Te estaría faltando corregir eso